# CSS: Floating two div elements with 100% width off screen?

Tags: css, html, css-float, off-screen

I remember asking this question a while back but i can't seem to find it again! I've searched but i can't seem to find the solution i'm looking for.

Let's say i have two divs with 100% width floated next to each other. As they take up the entire screenwidth, there is no longer any space left for them to float on, and therefore the second div appear below the first one. What i want is to make the second div continue floating off screen next to the first one.

I *think* the solution i got was to set the *display* property to something else, but i'm not entirely sure.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `overflow: scroll;` or `overflow: hidden;` depending on whether you want the scroll bar to appear.

Comment: No, i don't want to be able to scroll to the right. I just want it to be off screen, invisible.

Comment: If you want it invisible, why don't you just set `display: none`?

Comment: Because if i set the width of the first div to 0px i want the other div to be fully visible again.

Comment: Okay, are you saying you *do* or *do not* want partial visibility? If you want to allow partial visibility, `overflow: hidden;` should work.

Comment: It's suppose to be visible, but off screen (hence not visible because you can't see what's off screen). If i set the first divs witdh to 0px i want the second div to take up the space (to move in-screen again). It's kind of hard to describe without visually pointing it out...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you would have to have a container and set the container width to 200%. The two inside divs with 50% width will fit inside.

```
#container_div{ width:200%}
.inner_div {width:50%}
```

Comment: Hmm, yeah i suppose that might work. But i'd have to set the .inner_div to 50% width, then. See what i mean? But i'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

You could position them absolutely.

```
<body style="padding:0; margin:0">
    <div style="width:100%; position:relative;">
        <div style="width:100%; height:100px; background:#f90; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;">COLUMN1</div>
        <div style="width:100%; height:100px; background:#f00; position:absolute; top:0; left:100%;">COLUMN2</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

They are positioned absolutely within the bound of the relatively positioned parent.

Then you switch between them you just switch the left values, from 0 to 100% respectively.

- heights and background colours are just to see whats going on :)

Answer (score 0):

give 50% width to both div
so they occupy 100% width together